# Cannot get file list using phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

Our bank has set up an account that we can log into with SFTP and download files.  I am trying to use phpseclib for this.  I have used it many times before with no problem but with this remote site I am unable to retrieve a list of files in a directory.

I am able to log in with FileZilla and the files are there.

I have tried:

```
    $sftp = new SFTP($hostname, $port);
    if (!$sftp->login($username, $password))
    {
        log_message('tcx', 'SFTP Login Failed');
        exit;
    }

    $sftp->chdir('./Outbox');
    echo $sftp->pwd(); //returns /Outbox
    $file_list = $sftp->nlist(); // returns empty array
```

and tried using nlist method with recursive option:

```
    $sftp = new SFTP($hostname, $port);
    if (!$sftp->login($username, $password))
    {
        log_message('tcx', 'SFTP Login Failed');
        exit;
    }

    echo $sftp->pwd(); //returns /
    $file_list = $sftp->nlist('.', TRUE); // returns Array ( [0] => Inbox [1] => Outbox )
```

I though maybe it had something to do with the permissions set on the files so I set up a test on another remote system using the same permissions and I was able to list those files OK.

In FileZilla I enabled debug logging and can see:

```
Status: Connecting to XXXXX.com:10022...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  Going to execute C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\fzsftp.exe
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "user@XXXXX.com" 10022
Trace:  Connecting to 123.456.789 port 10022
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.45.1
Trace:  Server version: SSH-2.0-SFTP Server
Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:  Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Trace:  Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:  ssh-rsa 2048 68:ea:3a:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXX
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Trace:  Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Trace:  Using keyboard-interactive authentication. inst_len: 28, num_prompts: 1
Command:    Pass: *********
Trace:  Access granted
Trace:  Opening session as main channel
Trace:  Opened main channel
Trace:  Started a shell/command
Status: Connected to XXXXXX.com
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    pwd
Response:   Current directory is: "/"
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 1
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    ls
Status: Listing directory /
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/Outbox"...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    cd "/Outbox"
Response:   New directory is: "/Outbox"
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CSftpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 2
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    ls
Status: Listing directory /Outbox
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CSftpListOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Status: Directory listing of "/Outbox" successful
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

It is using the ls command to list the files.  Can that be done with phpseclib using $sftp->exec() method?  I looked around for some examples using this but really didn't find anything that applied.

Anyone have a clue what is going wrong here?

Edit
Output from SFTP Logs:

```
-> NET_SFTP_INIT (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:03                                      ....

<- NET_SFTP_VERSION (0.0843s)
00000000  00:00:00:03:00:00:00:13:6e:65:77:6c:69:6e:65:40  ........newline@
00000010  76:61:6e:64:79:6b:65:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:0a  vandyke.com.....

-> NET_SFTP_REALPATH (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:2e                                   .....

<- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.091s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:2f:00:00:00:01:2f:00:00  ......../..../..
00000010  00:0f:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:00:00:00:01:2c:00:00  .............,..
00000020  00:64:00:00:41:c0:5d:97:6b:1f:5d:97:6b:1f        .d..A.].k.].k.

-> NET_SFTP_OPENDIR (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:07:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78                 ..../Outbox

<- NET_SFTP_HANDLE (0.0892s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:30                                   ....0

-> NET_SFTP_CLOSE (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:30                                   ....0

<- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0844s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:17:54:68:65:20:6f:70:65:72  ........The oper
00000010  61:74:69:6f:6e:20:63:6f:6d:70:6c:65:74:65:64:00  ation completed.
00000020  00:00:00                                         ...

-> NET_SFTP_OPENDIR (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:07:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78                 ..../Outbox

<- NET_SFTP_HANDLE (0.0898s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:31                                   ....1

-> NET_SFTP_READDIR (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:31                                   ....1

<- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0904s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:22:45:4f:46:20:72:65:61:63  ......."EOF reac
00000010  68:65:64:20:66:6f:72:20:4d:61:69:6c:62:6f:78:20  hed for Mailbox 
00000020  5b:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78:5d:2e:00:00:00:00        [/Outbox].....

-> NET_SFTP_CLOSE (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:31                                   ....1

<- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0843s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:17:54:68:65:20:6f:70:65:72  ........The oper
00000010  61:74:69:6f:6e:20:63:6f:6d:70:6c:65:74:65:64:00  ation completed.
00000020  00:00:00
```

SSH Logs

```
<-
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:53:46:54:50:20:53:65:72  SSH-2.0-SFTP Ser
00000010  76:65:72:0d:0a                                   ver..

->
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69  SSH-2.0-phpsecli
00000010  62:5f:32:2e:30:20:28:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:6c:2c:20  b_2.0 (openssl, 
00000020  62:63:6d:61:74:68:29:0d:0a                       bcmath)..

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.2135, network: 0s)
00000000  f0:30:0e:c6:ea:6f:b2:08:ec:a7:2d:09:97:2f:42:a5  .0...o....-../B.
00000010  00:00:01:7c:63:75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39:2d:73  ...|curve25519-s
00000020  68:61:32:35:36:2c:63:75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39  ha256,curve25519
00000030  2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:40:6c:69:62:73:73:68:2e:6f  -sha256@libssh.o
00000040  72:67:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73  rg,ecdh-sha2-nis
00000050  74:70:32:35:36:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d  tp256,ecdh-sha2-
00000060  6e:69:73:74:70:33:38:34:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68  nistp384,ecdh-sh
00000070  61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70:35:32:31:2c:64:69:66:66  a2-nistp521,diff
00000080  69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70  ie-hellman-group
00000090  2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36  -exchange-sha256
000000a0  2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d  ,diffie-hellman-
000000b0  67:72:6f:75:70:2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73  group-exchange-s
000000c0  68:61:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d  ha1,diffie-hellm
000000d0  61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:32:35  an-group14-sha25
000000e0  36:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e  6,diffie-hellman
000000f0  2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69  -group14-sha1,di
00000100  66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f  ffie-hellman-gro
00000110  75:70:31:35:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66:66  up15-sha512,diff
00000120  69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70  ie-hellman-group
00000130  31:36:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65  16-sha512,diffie
00000140  2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:37  -hellman-group17
00000150  2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68  -sha512,diffie-h
00000160  65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:38:2d:73  ellman-group18-s
00000170  68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c  ha512,diffie-hel
00000180  6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:2d:73:68:61:31  lman-group1-sha1
00000190  00:00:00:71:73:73:68:2d:65:64:32:35:35:31:39:2c  ...qssh-ed25519,
000001a0  65:63:64:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70  ecdsa-sha2-nistp
000001b0  32:35:36:2c:65:63:64:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e  256,ecdsa-sha2-n
000001c0  69:73:74:70:33:38:34:2c:65:63:64:73:61:2d:73:68  istp384,ecdsa-sh
000001d0  61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70:35:32:31:2c:72:73:61:2d  a2-nistp521,rsa-
000001e0  73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61  sha2-256,rsa-sha
000001f0  32:2d:35:31:32:2c:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:2c:73:73  2-512,ssh-rsa,ss
00000200  68:2d:64:73:73:00:00:01:01:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d  h-dss....aes128-
00000210  67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c  gcm@openssh.com,
00000220  61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73  aes256-gcm@opens
00000230  73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74  sh.com,aes128-ct
00000240  72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73  r,aes192-ctr,aes
00000250  32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63  256-ctr,aes128-c
00000260  62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65  bc,aes192-cbc,ae
00000270  73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73  s256-cbc,blowfis
00000280  68:2d:63:74:72:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63  h-ctr,blowfish-c
00000290  62:63:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73  bc,3des-ctr,3des
000002a0  2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d  -cbc,twofish128-
000002b0  63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63  ctr,twofish192-c
000002c0  74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:74  tr,twofish256-ct
000002d0  72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63  r,twofish128-cbc
000002e0  2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c  ,twofish192-cbc,
000002f0  74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74  twofish256-cbc,t
00000300  77:6f:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:00:00:01:01:61:65  wofish-cbc....ae
00000310  73:31:32:38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68  s128-gcm@openssh
00000320  2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:67:63:6d:40  .com,aes256-gcm@
00000330  6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:31  openssh.com,aes1
00000340  32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74  28-ctr,aes192-ct
00000350  72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73  r,aes256-ctr,aes
00000360  31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63  128-cbc,aes192-c
00000370  62:63:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c  bc,aes256-cbc,bl
00000380  6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:74:72:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66  owfish-ctr,blowf
00000390  69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:74:72  ish-cbc,3des-ctr
000003a0  2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73  ,3des-cbc,twofis
000003b0  68:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68  h128-ctr,twofish
000003c0  31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32  192-ctr,twofish2
000003d0  35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32  56-ctr,twofish12
000003e0  38:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32  8-cbc,twofish192
000003f0  2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d  -cbc,twofish256-
00000400  63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:00  cbc,twofish-cbc.
00000410  00:00:f7:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36  ...hmac-sha2-256
00000420  2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d  -etm@openssh.com
00000430  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d:65  ,hmac-sha2-512-e
00000440  74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75  tm@openssh.com,u
00000450  6d:61:63:2d:36:34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73  mac-64-etm@opens
00000460  73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:2d  sh.com,umac-128-
00000470  65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c  etm@openssh.com,
00000480  68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70  hmac-sha1-etm@op
00000490  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73  enssh.com,hmac-s
000004a0  68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61  ha2-256,hmac-sha
000004b0  32:2d:35:31:32:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:40:6f:70  2-512,umac-64@op
000004c0  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31  enssh.com,umac-1
000004d0  32:38:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68  28@openssh.com,h
000004e0  6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63  mac-sha1-96,hmac
000004f0  2d:73:68:61:31:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39  -sha1,hmac-md5-9
00000500  36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00:f7:68:6d  6,hmac-md5....hm
00000510  61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2d:65:74:6d:40  ac-sha2-256-etm@
00000520  6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63  openssh.com,hmac
00000530  2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70  -sha2-512-etm@op
00000540  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36  enssh.com,umac-6
00000550  34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f  4-etm@openssh.co
00000560  6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f  m,umac-128-etm@o
00000570  70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  penssh.com,hmac-
00000580  73:68:61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68  sha1-etm@openssh
00000590  2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32  .com,hmac-sha2-2
000005a0  35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32  56,hmac-sha2-512
000005b0  2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68  ,umac-64@openssh
000005c0  2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:40:6f:70  .com,umac-128@op
000005d0  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73  enssh.com,hmac-s
000005e0  68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31  ha1-96,hmac-sha1
000005f0  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61  ,hmac-md5-96,hma
00000600  63:2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00  c-md5....none...
00000610  04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  .none...........
00000620  00:00                                            ..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  1b:65:e5:8f:81:62:f3:ab:02:03:b8:47:ac:de:9f:e9  .e...b.....G....
00000010  00:00:01:86:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d  ....diffie-hellm
00000020  61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:63  an-group1-sha1,c
00000030  75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36  urve25519-sha256
00000040  40:6c:69:62:73:73:68:2e:6f:72:67:2c:64:69:66:66  @libssh.org,diff
00000050  69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70  ie-hellman-group
00000060  2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36  -exchange-sha256
00000070  2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d  ,diffie-hellman-
00000080  67:72:6f:75:70:31:38:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64  group18-sha512,d
00000090  69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72  iffie-hellman-gr
000000a0  6f:75:70:31:37:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66  oup17-sha512,dif
000000b0  66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75  fie-hellman-grou
000000c0  70:31:36:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66:66:69  p16-sha512,diffi
000000d0  65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31  e-hellman-group1
000000e0  35:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d  5-sha512,diffie-
000000f0  68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:34:2d  hellman-group14-
00000100  73:68:61:32:35:36:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65  sha256,diffie-he
00000110  6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68  llman-group14-sh
00000120  61:31:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73  a1,ecdh-sha2-nis
00000130  74:70:32:35:36:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d  tp256,ecdh-sha2-
00000140  6e:69:73:74:70:33:38:34:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68  nistp384,ecdh-sh
00000150  61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70:35:32:31:2c:64:69:66:66  a2-nistp521,diff
00000160  69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70  ie-hellman-group
00000170  2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:72  -exchange-sha1,r
00000180  73:61:32:30:34:38:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:2c:72:73  sa2048-sha256,rs
00000190  61:31:30:32:34:2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:07:73:73  a1024-sha1....ss
000001a0  68:2d:72:73:61:00:00:00:41:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d  h-rsa...Aaes256-
000001b0  63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61  cbc,aes128-ctr,a
000001c0  65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36  es192-ctr,aes256
000001d0  2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c  -ctr,aes128-cbc,
000001e0  61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:00:00:00:41:61:65  aes192-cbc...Aae
000001f0  73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d  s256-cbc,aes128-
00000200  63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61  ctr,aes192-ctr,a
00000210  65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38  es256-ctr,aes128
00000220  2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:00  -cbc,aes192-cbc.
00000230  00:00:17:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36  ...hmac-sha2-256
00000240  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:17:68:6d  ,hmac-sha1....hm
00000250  61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63  ac-sha2-256,hmac
00000260  2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:09:6e:6f:6e:65:2c:7a:6c  -sha1....none,zl
00000270  69:62:00:00:00:09:6e:6f:6e:65:2c:7a:6c:69:62:00  ib....none,zlib.
00000280  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00              ............

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT (since last: 0.0574, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:20:d4:f2:2a:ee:1a:74:66:62:ac:00:7e:74  ... ..*..tfb..~t
00000010  0d:1b:4d:77:db:13:b2:c7:5b:64:25:8e:19:b1:23:12  ..Mw....[d%...#.
00000020  37:43:3e:2d                                      7C>-

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY (since last: 0.1535, network: 0.1535s)
00000000  00:00:01:17:00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00  ........ssh-rsa.
00000010  00:00:03:01:00:01:00:00:01:01:00:8e:ec:e5:13:6f  ...............o
00000020  a6:a7:d9:ba:17:26:1b:9f:35:01:00:e9:2a:76:0c:bd  .....&..5...*v..
00000030  7d:01:f1:79:d6:ec:13:47:47:3e:37:a0:8a:9c:53:2e  }..y...GG>7...S.
00000040  86:25:08:ff:63:06:3c:38:e9:ee:4a:84:a4:14:e2:8c  .%..c..8..J.....
00000050  59:60:94:9a:37:1a:d2:74:63:eb:34:cf:0e:e1:51:3c  Y`..7..tc.4...Q.
00000060  86:1c:8e:0a:ca:17:3b:d2:9b:53:80:9a:d5:88:b7:d8  ......;..S......
00000070  9f:9c:9a:9c:7b:ec:28:ec:31:f0:db:c3:74:74:4d:80  ....{.(.1...ttM.
00000080  75:09:59:0b:b1:d6:82:3a:c8:0a:b4:e8:55:cc:1f:78  u.Y....:....U..x
00000090  a3:ae:ed:ce:75:3c:37:99:3a:94:25:f2:99:63:c3:00  ....u.7.:.%..c..
000000a0  8c:b8:a6:1c:7d:19:96:41:42:2a:37:20:77:91:55:a1  ....}..AB*7 w.U.
000000b0  21:0c:bc:be:db:f6:7c:3f:d7:89:bc:82:48:f1:a7:f7  !.....|?....H...
000000c0  61:16:f2:f5:9d:c1:a4:19:61:b6:f3:dd:2a:b1:e7:b0  a.......a...*...
000000d0  46:47:de:28:4e:d9:5e:d5:a9:b9:27:72:06:cf:4c:5e  FG.(N.^...'r..L^
000000e0  8f:9f:1b:3f:13:77:91:6c:93:76:d9:79:db:ae:58:ff  ...?.w.l.v.y..X.
000000f0  24:49:29:79:01:29:64:81:5c:c2:1a:e1:1c:9e:f4:d4  $I)y.)d.\.......
00000100  f3:53:10:1f:c8:ea:36:41:d9:a4:a8:e7:61:05:26:8c  .S....6A....a.&.
00000110  10:ef:ee:8b:15:66:fe:3a:ea:a7:2d:00:00:00:20:b1  .....f.:..-... .
00000120  29:b3:a7:04:ed:09:6b:8e:7e:b8:ab:5a:ab:79:15:e6  ).....k.~..Z.y..
00000130  dd:57:01:01:80:59:4c:2c:c0:e3:0d:27:0d:a6:52:00  .W...YL,...'..R.
00000140  00:01:0f:00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00:00  .......ssh-rsa..
00000150  01:00:6d:fa:65:f3:58:b6:77:9f:94:6d:63:fa:be:8f  ..m.e.X.w..mc...
00000160  1f:be:99:85:03:00:b7:f6:c4:20:89:79:23:49:b9:7b  ......... .y#I.{
00000170  eb:a5:5a:99:23:ac:ef:a9:7d:ff:47:1a:b6:43:7c:56  ..Z.#...}.G..C|V
00000180  86:e3:6b:f7:b5:e9:76:be:74:e5:ef:1c:c4:03:bc:ef  ..k...v.t.......
00000190  90:4e:b9:e3:2e:3e:89:63:0e:eb:0e:51:37:79:cf:ba  .N...>.c...Q7y..
000001a0  86:90:9e:0b:92:c0:a5:cc:63:88:aa:19:e2:36:11:0f  ........c....6..
000001b0  0c:6e:4c:cf:f7:cd:5b:0f:3d:33:ff:d8:c1:75:eb:e1  .nL...[.=3...u..
000001c0  e9:67:8a:66:ff:e0:a2:f1:5a:c2:29:90:41:b2:b5:a5  .g.f....Z.).A...
000001d0  27:da:4a:97:be:cc:cb:76:54:c4:41:28:b0:15:5a:11  '.J....vT.A(..Z.
000001e0  c0:dc:8a:2e:2d:6c:bc:12:6f:01:bf:47:88:84:a4:d2  ....-l..o..G....
000001f0  24:9d:e0:26:fe:7c:9d:30:47:c7:cb:c6:9e:fe:f5:43  $..&.|.0G......C
00000200  65:51:e3:4e:69:22:d4:69:e7:87:47:a5:09:0a:74:92  eQ.Ni".i..G...t.
00000210  80:86:70:20:d6:dc:0b:94:2c:39:78:d8:98:2a:c5:63  ..p ....,9x..*.c
00000220  a8:ad:8e:a4:9f:e7:69:58:f5:db:60:6f:13:1b:14:18  ......iX..`o....
00000230  36:f9:2e:5b:91:11:98:47:0f:24:05:06:18:40:46:9f  6..[...G.$...@F.
00000240  c7:1d:87:ee:fd:98:0e:67:0d:c9:57:0b:07:85:99:52  .......g..W....R
00000250  b0:4f                                            .O

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.0637, network: 0s)


<- NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0, network: 0s)


-> NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST (since last: 0.0006, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68  ....ssh-userauth

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT (since last: 0.2068, network: 0.2068s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68  ....ssh-userauth

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:09:74:61:78:63:6f:6e:6e:65:78:00:00:00  ....xxxxxxxxx...
00000010  0e:73:73:68:2d:63:6f:6e:6e:65:63:74:69:6f:6e:00  .ssh-connection.
00000020  00:00:08:70:61:73:73:77:6f:72:64:00:00:00:00:08  ...password.....
00000030  70:61:73:73:77:6f:72:64                          password

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:23:53:53:48:20:53:65:72:76:65:72:20:73  ...#SSH Server s
00000010  75:70:70:6f:72:74:69:6e:67:20:53:46:54:50:20:61  upporting SFTP a
00000020  6e:64:20:53:43:50:0a:00:00:00:00                 nd SCP.....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS (since last: 0.1186, network: 0.1186s)


-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:07:73:65:73:73:69:6f:6e:00:00:01:00:7f  ....session.....
00000010  ff:ff:ff:00:00:40:00                             .....@.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (since last: 0.104, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:84:d0  ................

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09:73:75:62:73:79:73:74:65  ........subsyste
00000010  6d:01:00:00:00:04:73:66:74:70                    m.....sftp

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST (since last: 0.1045, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:40:00:00                          .....@..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00                                      ....

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09:00:00:00:05:01:00:00:00  ................
00000010  03                                               .

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1053, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:25:00:00:00:21:02:00:00:00  .......%...!....
00000010  03:00:00:00:13:6e:65:77:6c:69:6e:65:40:76:61:6e  .....newline@van
00000020  64:79:6b:65:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:0a           dyke.com.....

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:10:00:00:00  ................
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:2e                                ......

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1102, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:37:00:00:00:33:68:00:00:00  .......7...3h...
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:2f:00:00:00:01:2f:00  ........./..../.
00000020  00:00:0f:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:00:00:00:01:2c:00  ..............,.
00000030  00:00:64:00:00:41:c0:5d:97:6b:1f:5d:97:6b:1f     ..d..A.].k.].k.

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:14:00:00:00:10:0b:00:00:00  ................
00000010  01:00:00:00:07:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78              ...../Outbox

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1105, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:66:00:00:00  ............f...
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:30                                .....0

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:04:00:00:00  ................
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:30                                .....0

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.105, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:2c:00:00:00:28:65:00:00:00  .......,...(e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:17:54:68:65:20:6f:70:65  .........The ope
00000020  72:61:74:69:6f:6e:20:63:6f:6d:70:6c:65:74:65:64  ration completed
00000030  00:00:00:00                                      ....

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:14:00:00:00:10:0b:00:00:00  ................
00000010  01:00:00:00:07:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78              ...../Outbox

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1094, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:66:00:00:00  ............f...
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:31                                .....1

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:0c:00:00:00  ................
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:31                                .....1

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1113, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:37:00:00:00:33:65:00:00:00  .......7...3e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:22:45:4f:46:20:72:65:61  ........"EOF rea
00000020  63:68:65:64:20:66:6f:72:20:4d:61:69:6c:62:6f:78  ched for Mailbox
00000030  20:5b:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78:5d:2e:00:00:00:00      [/Outbox].....

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0e:00:00:00:0a:04:00:00:00  ................
00000010  01:00:00:00:01:31                                .....1

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.105, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:2c:00:00:00:28:65:00:00:00  .......,...(e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:17:54:68:65:20:6f:70:65  .........The ope
00000020  72:61:74:69:6f:6e:20:63:6f:6d:70:6c:65:74:65:64  ration completed
00000030  00:00:00:00                                      ....
```

SFTP Log using nlist method

```
-> NET_SFTP_INIT (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:03                                      ....

<- NET_SFTP_VERSION (0.108s)
00000000  00:00:00:03:00:00:00:13:6e:65:77:6c:69:6e:65:40  ........newline@
00000010  76:61:6e:64:79:6b:65:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:01:0a  vandyke.com.....

-> NET_SFTP_REALPATH (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:2e                                   .....

<- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.1123s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:2f:00:00:00:01:2f:00:00  ......../..../..
00000010  00:0f:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:00:00:00:01:2c:00:00  .............,..
00000020  00:64:00:00:41:c0:5d:97:6b:1f:5d:97:6b:1f        .d..A.].k.].k.

-> NET_SFTP_OPENDIR (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:07:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78                 ..../Outbox

<- NET_SFTP_HANDLE (0.1122s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:30                                   ....0

-> NET_SFTP_READDIR (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:30                                   ....0

<- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.1137s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:22:45:4f:46:20:72:65:61:63  ......."EOF reac
00000010  68:65:64:20:66:6f:72:20:4d:61:69:6c:62:6f:78:20  hed for Mailbox 
00000020  5b:2f:4f:75:74:62:6f:78:5d:2e:00:00:00:00        [/Outbox].....

-> NET_SFTP_CLOSE (0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:30                                   ....0

<- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.1084s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:17:54:68:65:20:6f:70:65:72  ........The oper
00000010  61:74:69:6f:6e:20:63:6f:6d:70:6c:65:74:65:64:00  ation completed.
00000020  00:00:00                                         ...
```

Comment: Filezilla will not show the file list in the log.  I am looking at FileZilla right now and it is showing files in the files pane.

Comment: Actually it will if the option is selected for it to show raw directory listing.  I have confirmed again that FileZilla will list the files.

Comment: What version are you using @Tom Vaughan

Comment: @gbengawale I have tried using version 2.0.23 and dev-master.

Comment: "_Can that be done with phpseclib using $sftp->exec() method?_" You could do `$sftp->exec('ls -latr');`. As for `$sftp->nlist()` giving an empty result...  what do the SFTP logs say? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and `$sftp->getSFTPLog();` after the `nlist()` calls.

Comment: Also, what'd be more helpful than the FileZilla debug logs are the psftp logs. You can get those by doing `psftp -v -P 22 user@host`. I say that those would be more helpful because those contain the actual SSH packets instead of an English "translation" of them

Comment: @neubert I have updated post with SFTP logs.  Also, I tried using sftp directly in terminal and was able to log into remote system and list files.  So that is two other methods that were able to list the files.

Comment: Can you post the SSH2 logs as well? You can get those by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` and `echo $sftp->getLog()`. The `psftp` logs would be cool as well. Thanks!

Comment: @neubert SSH logs added.  I tried to use psftp but keep getting invalid port error.  The remote host uses port 10022.

Comment: I almost wonder if it might work better if you did `$file_list = $sftp->nlist('./Outbox');` instead of `$sftp->chdir('./Outbox');`. As for psftp...  try `psftp -v -P 10022 user@host`. What version of psftp / PuTTY are you using?

Comment: @neubert The SFTP log shows that phpseclib correctly interprets the paths: `NET_SFTP_OPENDIR ...   ..../Outbox`. - Though it is still worth trying (maybe rather `$sftp->nlist('/Outbox')` with no `chdir`) - It can be a server-side bug. -- @Tom, do you have an access to server-side logs?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - yah - it's a server-side bug I'm wondering about. The `chdir` is causing an extra `NET_SFTP_OPENDIR` to be sent (presumably as confirmation that the directory you're `chdir`'ing into actually is a directory) and maybe the other SFTP clients aren't doing that. Like since SFTP doesn't natively support `chdir` phpseclib kinda emulates it whereas other clients might not.

Comment: @neubert I tried using just nlist and not doing chdir and had same result.  I don't have access to server logs since it is a bank.  I am using the latest version of putty, 0.73.  I have posted the SFTP log while only using  nlist method.  I will check with the bank to see if they can do something.

Comment: Can you post a log file from WinSCP showing the directory listing with logging level set to Debug 2?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I put the WinSCP log on pastebin.  It is too large to post here.  https://pastebin.com/wuYFSSJC

Comment: That is...  weird. https://pastebin.com/vraiLwne Those are the SSH logs extracted from the WinSCP logs. The server is giving phpseclib a completely different response for the same requests. WinSCP's logs are including the message number and the request ID whereas the phpseclib is not. So WinSCP supports SFTPv6 but the server only supports SFTPv3 so SFTPv3 is used. phpseclib only implements SFTPv3. Is the server, per chance, deleting the files after you check the directory?

Comment: Can you [configure WinSCP to use SFTP version 3](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp), to get equivalent logs?

Comment: @neubert No, it does not delete files just by listing contents of directory but it does delete the files automatically after they are downloaded.  Would that matter?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  WinSCP logs using SFTP version 3 are here: https://pastebin.com/mBxbNEx1  I do have a workaround in place for now if phpseclib isn't going to work.  I wrote a bash script that downloads the files using scp.  But doing that means I have a two step process, downloading and then later processing in PHP.  I really appreciate both of you for helping me out on this!!

Comment: phpseclib imo sends the *exactly same requests* to the server as WinSCP. Yet the server responds differently. It's imo bug in the server. -- You can try the workaround @neubert has suggested above with `$sftp->exec('ls -latr')`.

Comment: Shot in the dark idea: change the identification string that phpseclib uses. https://pastebin.com/P0Y4jGme shows how to do that.